# Rust: Implement trait in another crate

Tags: rust

I wanna create a rust application which consists of two crates: A core crate and an application crate. The core crate shall **not** use the std lib and **no heap** allocation, because it should run later also on embedded systems. In the core crate I wanna have some debug output possibility, but this shall be implemented in the application crate. So the question I have is, how do I implement such a debug output function usable in the core crate?

The idea was to create a trait:

core/lib.rs

```rust
// Storing the object which implements MyDebug?
// Initialization function?

pub trait MyDebug {
    fn mydebug(text: &str);
}

pub fn custom_function() {
    mydebug("Hello World");
}
```

application/main.rs

```rust
use core;

struct DebugObject {
}

impl core::MyDebug for DebugObject {
    fn mydebug(text: &str) {
        // do something
    }
}

fn main() {
   // Some initialization
   DebugObject obj;
   core::initialize_debug(&obj);

   custom_function();
}
```

Is this even possible or do you think it is cleaner to pass always the debug object?

```rust
use core;

struct DebugObject {
}

impl core::MyDebug for DebugObject {
    fn mydebug(text: &str) {
        // do something
    }
}

fn main() {
   // Some initialization
   DebugObject obj;

   custom_function(&obj);
}
```

### Update

One solution I found:

core/lib.rs:

```rust
#![no_std]

pub trait MyDebug {
    fn debug(&self, text: &str);
}

static mut DEBUG: Option<&'static dyn MyDebug> = None;
static mut DEBUG_INITIALIZED: bool = false;

pub unsafe fn initialize_debug<T: MyDebug>(debugger: &'static T) {
    if !DEBUG_INITIALIZED {
        DEBUG_INITIALIZED = true;
        DEBUG = Some(debugger);
    }
}

fn debug(text: &str) {
    unsafe {
        if let Some(debugger) = DEBUG {
            debugger.debug(text);
        }
    }
}

pub fn function() {
    debug("Test123");
}
```

main.rs

```rust
use core;
struct MyStruct {

}

impl core::MyDebug for MyStruct {

    fn debug(&self, text: &str) {
        println!("{}", text);
    }
}

const MY_STATIC_STRUCT: MyStruct = MyStruct {
};

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        core::initialize_debug(&MY_STATIC_STRUCT);
    }

    core::function();
}
```

Comment: Both snippets should work. The first one looks a bit more like a plug-in system, while the second one is more functional. In case of doubt, I'd probably go for the latter, but it's really a matter of taste/how it feels to use in practice.

Comment: The second is easy to implement, but has a few limitations when using other functionality as well, so it might that I have to pass a lot of objects in the future. For the first example, I don't know how to implement the object in core/lib.rs

Comment: Are you ok with depending on std or do you wish to depend only on Rust's core library? The latter means no Mutex, which makes things more complicated.

Comment: The problem is on microcontroller std does not exist and therefore I have to live without.

Comment: Your solution is clearly better than mine.

Comment: But the inspiration came also from your one. 

Answer (score 0):

If you're 100% certain that you're only going to call `core::initialize_debug` one startup, you can go the `unsafe` way:

```rust
pub trait MyDebug { /* ... */ }

static mut DEBUG: Option<Box<dyn MyDebug>> = None;

pub unsafe fn initialize_debug<T: MyDebug>(debugger: Box<T>) where T: 'static {
    DEBUG = Some(debugger)
}

fn debugger() -> Option<&'static dyn MyDebug> {
    unsafe {
        DEBUG.as_ref().map(Box::as_ref)
    }
}
```

(I'm currently trying to come up with a way to do this without `unsafe` or memory allocations in core)

Comment: But Box is inside std so I can't use it or is this a different implementation? heapless::pool::boxed is not available for x64 as replacement

Comment: Ah, you're right.

Comment: Not sure if it is possible to get an example without unsafe?

Comment: I'm starting to believe that it's not possible, at least not out of the box as core doesn't have any of the synchronization primitives that would let DEBUG be Sync + Send.